# Autoclick action in X,Y coordinates after loading the web page

Tags: javascript, automation

Is there a script that after loading of a page or xxx time automatically clicked on a particular part of a page even if that part of the page javascript?
I hope you understand :)

Comment: Impossible to simulate a click event. But you can trigger a click on a random element of the page.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but are you sure that there´s no other workaround for your issue? Imagine that if you solve a problem that way, there is a bunch of potential bugs that could arise, e.g., you change the position of something, you make zoom or you open your webpage in a mobile device.

Comment: @user1373334  if you know what I want to achieve, is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

You can something like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can A jQuery example:

```
 function simulateClick(x, y) {
     jQuery(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).click();
 }
 simulateClick(100, 250);
 simulateClick(400, 250);
```